# How to render a component view in a module?

Tags: module-display, mvc, view

## Brief

**I have a component and have a form in it. And I want to render the same form in a module.**

An example can be core Joomla article edit form
**components/com_content/views/form/tmpl/edit.php**
which is rendered based on
**components/com_content/models/forms/article.xml**

As far as I can see it's not possible to load a component view in the module in this case. 
**Am I right?**

## One option

I see is to use an AJAX to get my form from my component loaded like **?option=com_mycomponent&view=myform&tmpl=component** and to inject the from HTML into my main page DOM. An ugly way. So I'd not like to use this way. 
**Am I right?**

## Another way

So I want to be [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) in the module.

1. I don't want to repeat view part (for example load XML form and bind data to it). 
   *How to stay DRY in the module with the view part?*
2. Don't repeat the template part rendering HTML (**/views/form/tmpl/edit.php**)
   Here the things are simpler. I can use JLayouts instead of the **tmpl/default.php** approach in my component. 
   So I can reuse the layouts anywhere (in a module, a plugin).

## What I beg for

Please, tell me how to behave in the most proper way in this case. Or give me a component->module or a component->template example which implements such an approach. So I can investigate the code.

**P.S.**
I wonder why mod_login uses own form template instead of reusing the same component view. That would be a nice example for guys like me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is code I write time ago for Joomla 1.5, you will need adapt it for jooma 3.x (JRequest -> JInput, ...), and surely there is more elegant way to do this.

This is the basic part of module.php

My component is 'com_alojamiento', the controller is 'alojamientoController'

Get current option, view, layout, ... to restore it after render.

```
$optionant = JRequest::getCmd('option',null);
$view = JRequest::getCmd('view',null);
$layout = JRequest::getCmd('layout',null);
$task = JRequest::getCmd('task',null);
```

Then set your parameters, option, view, layout and wathever you need, ids,...

```
$yourcomponent = '';
$yourview = '';
$yourlayout = '';
$yourtask = '';
```

Set it in JRequest (JInput in 3.x)

```
JRequest::setVar('option', $yourcomponent); 
JRequest::setVar('view', $yourview);
JRequest::setVar('layout', $yourlayout);
JRequest::setVar('task', 'yourtask');
```

Set additional parameters like id, customer_id, etc.

Language files

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$lang->load('com_alojamiento', JPATH_SITE);
```

Load the controller

```
if (!class_exists('alojamientoController')) {
    require_once (JPATH_SITE .DS. 'components' .DS. 'com_alojamiento' .DS. 'controller.php');
}
$controller = new alojamientoController();
$controller->addModelPath(JPATH_SITE .DS. 'components' .DS. 'com_alojamiento' .DS. 'models' .DS);

$controller->setProperties(array(
    '_basePath' => JPATH_SITE .DS. 'components' .DS. 'com_alojamiento',
    '_path' => array(
        'view' => array(
            JPATH_SITE .DS. 'components' .DS. 'com_alojamiento' .DS. 'views'
            ),
        'model' => array(
            JPATH_SITE .DS. 'components' .DS. 'com_alojamiento' .DS. 'models'
            )
        )
    ));
```

And render

```
ob_start();
$controller->execute($task);
$salida = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

After render, restore current values

```
JRequest::setVar('option', $optionant);
JRequest::setVar('view', $view);
JRequest::setVar('layout', $layout);
JRequest::setVar('task', $task);
```

Component view contents are in $salida variable to use in your module tpl

Comment: perfect, you made my day.

Answer (score 1):

When I want to use a component in a module I use Regular Labs's Component Anywhere extension.

https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/componentsanywhere

Perhaps that could be an example for you to review.

HTH